# Having already proved $A\vdash B$, $B\vdash C$ and $\neg C$, is this a fine proof proving $\vdash\neg A$?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

since $A\vdash B$ is true $A\rightarrow B$ is also true.

since $B\vdash C$ is true $B\rightarrow C$ is also true.

1. $\quad\bullet$
2. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; A$ --- assumption
3. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; A\rightarrow B$ --- Theorem Intro
4. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; B$ --- By $\rightarrow$  Elim 2,3
5. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; B\rightarrow C$ --- Theorem Intro
6. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; C$ --- By $\rightarrow$  Elim 4,5
7. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; \neg C$ --- Theorem Intro
8. $\quad\bullet\quad\bullet\; \bot$ --- $\bot$  Intro 6,7
9. $\quad\bullet\; \neg A$ --- $\neg$ Intro 2 $-$ 8

Comment: What's the difference between $A \vdash B$ and $A\to B$?

Comment: @fleablood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent

Comment: So no difference here?

Comment: Correct, but the rule used in 9 is $\lnot$ Intro and not RAA.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can you plz tell why it's not RAA?

Comment: RAA is "from $\Gamma, \lnot \varphi  \vdash \bot$, derive $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: hmmm I see they're very much alike thou!

Comment: Yes; they are. The distinction is useful in order to separate classical and intuitionistic logic. With Double Negation or the Law of Excluded Middle, the two version are equivalent; in intuitionistiv logic, where DN and LEM do not hold, RAA does not hold also.