# Can we prove $\varphi\rightarrow (p \wedge \neg p)\vdash\neg\varphi$ by natural deduction and contradiction this way?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm thinking since $(p \wedge \neg p)$ is a contradiction we can do this:

1. $\;\varphi\rightarrow (p \wedge \neg p)$ --- premise
2. $\;\bullet\quad \varphi$ --- assumption
3. $\;\bullet\quad p \wedge \neg p$ --- $\rightarrow$ elim 1,2
4. $\;\neg\varphi$ --- $\neg$ intro 2 - 3

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: If that is how your $\neg Intro$ rule is defined, then that is a fine proof

Comment: @Bram28 Problem is as far as I've seen, assumption needs to lead to a $\bot$ symbol to use $\neg$ intro rule, and to get that symbol here I'd need to use $\wedge$ elim rule to achieve p and $\neg p$ first and then introduce $\bot$ using p and $\neg p$

Comment: Just added that as an Answer! :)

Comment: @Bram28 OMG X'D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by one of your earlier proofs:

[Having already proved $A\vdash B$, $B\vdash C$ and $\neg C$, is this a fine proof proving $\vdash\neg A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425505/having-already-proved-a-vdash-b-b-vdash-c-and-neg-c-is-this-a-fine-proo)

it seems that $\neg Intro$ in your system requires an explicit $\bot$. So, you probably want:

1. $\;\varphi\rightarrow (p \wedge \neg p)$ --- premise
2. $\;\bullet\quad \varphi$ --- assumption
3. $\;\bullet\quad p \wedge \neg p$ --- $\rightarrow$ elim 1,2
4. $\;\bullet\quad p$ --- $\land$ elim 3
5. $\;\bullet\quad \neg p$ --- $\land$ elim 3
6. $\;\bullet\quad \bot$ --- $\bot$ intro 4,5
7. $\;\neg\varphi$ --- $\neg$ intro 2 - 6

Comment: I just had this thought that, since $\bot$ symbol is nothing more than a $\varphi\wedge\neg\varphi$ we could omit it here, seems we should introduce $\bot$ anyway

Comment: @Pooria Yeah, it's equivalent, but in formal proofs you need the exact symbol patterns

Comment: @Pooria I find it strange to say that ⊥ is nothing more than (φ∧¬φ).  (φ∧¬φ) is a specific contradiction. I usually understand ⊥ as a constant false proposition, or in other words a contradiction.  Every single negation of a tautology is a contradiction, so one can potentially think of ⊥ as representing *any* of those formulas (but only one of them at a time in a particular context).   Thinking of (φ∧¬φ) as a shorthand for $\lnot$($\phi$→$\phi$) is not like thinking of ⊥ as a shorthand for $\lnot$($\phi$→$\phi$).  Truth functional equivalence is not identity.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Well I know that there are infinitely many contradictions, but as far as I've seen proofs in natural deduction, you introduce a contradiction refering to two formulas negated of each other, so it's only natural to think the contradiction used in natural deduction is the familiar $\varphi\wedge\neg\varphi$

Comment: @Pooria "you introduce a contradiction refering to two formulas negated of each other"  but one could just as easily infer ($\lnot$$\phi$$\land$$\phi$) in a single step instead, which also qualifies as a contradiction but isn't the same.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Well by commutativity they're the same!

Comment: @Pooria No, they are not the same by commutativity.  Truth-functional equivalence is not identity.  Perhaps as a more clear example to differentiate truth-functional equivalence from sameness, consider (p $\rightarrow$ p) and (((p $\rightarrow$ q) $\rightarrow$ p) $\rightarrow$ p).  Those two are truth-functionally equivalent, but definitely not the same.  Thus, truth-functional equivalence does not entail sameness.

Comment: Well I meant they're truth-functionally equivalent, I agree they're not totally the same ^^

Comment: Right. There is a difference between statements being equivalent and statements being identical.  Identity means that it is the exact same symbol string.  So, $p \land q$ is equivalent to $q \land p$, but it is not identical to it.  When you say that statements are the 'same', it is ambiguous whether you are talking about equivalence or identity, so it is best to just avoid that term.

Comment: I see $\neg \varphi$ as a shorthand for $\varphi \to \bot$, in which case $\varphi \land \neg \varphi$ becomes $\varphi \land (\varphi \to \bot)$, and using $\land$-elim we have $\varphi$ and $\varphi \to \bot$, then MP gives us $\bot$.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Perice's law is not true in intuitionistic logic :P

Comment: @KennyLau Nor is (p $\rightarrow$ (q $\rightarrow$ p)) true in relevant logic.  And $\lnot$(p$\land$$\lnot$p) is not true in Lukasiewicz three-valued logic.  And many other examples exist where classical tautologies are not true in other logics.

Comment: Also, $\lnot$$\phi$ can be a shorthand as you say.  It depends on the formal system you have at hand.

Comment: @KennyLau Also, though you can think of $\lnot$$\phi$ as a shorthand for ($\phi$$\rightarrow$0), a calculus with $\rightarrow$ and 0 as primitive will differ from one with $\rightarrow$ and $\lnot$ as primitive in significant ways.  For example, (0$\rightarrow$p) is not a theorem in a calculus with $\rightarrow$ and $\lnot$ as primitve.  Also, switching to Polish notation, in a calculus with C and 0 as primitive, CCpqCNqNp is a special case of CCpqCCqrCpr since CCpqCNqNp abbreviates CCpqCCq0Cp0, but this is not the case when C and N are primitive.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\varphi\rightarrow (p \land \neg p)}{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\varphi]}{p \land \neg p}{~\small\text{MP}}}{p \qquad \neg p}{~\small\land\text{E}}}{\bot}}{\neg\varphi}{~\small\neg\text{I}}}$$